# Combining index and value sorting with top-K selection

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe with columns `A`, `B`, `C`, and `data`.

I would like to:

1. Convert it to a multi-index dataframe with indices `A`, `B` and `C`
2. Sort the rows by the **the indices** `A` and `B` of this dataframe.
3. Within each `A` `B` pair of the index, sort the rows (i.e. the `C` index) **by the value on the column `data`**.
4. Get the top 20 rows within each such `A` `B` pair, according to the previous sorting on data.

This shouldn't be hard, but I have tried all sorts of approaches, and none of them give me what I want. The following, for example, is close, but it gives me only values for the first group of `A` `B` indices.

```
temp = mdf.set_index(['A', 'B','C']).sort_index()

# Sorting by value and retrieving the top 20 entries:
func = lambda x: x.sort('data', ascending=False).head(20)
temp = temp.groupby(level=['A','B'],as_index=False).apply(func)

# Drop the dummy index (?) introduced in the line above
temp = temp.reset_index(level=0)['data']
```

## Update:

```
def create_random_multi_index():
  df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [np.random.random_integers(10) for x in xrange(500)], 
                     'B' : [np.random.random_integers(10) for x in xrange(500)], 
                     'C' : [np.random.random_integers(10) for x in xrange(500)],
                     'data' : randn(500) })

  return df
```

E.g. of what I am looking for (showing **top 3 elements**, note how the data is sorted within each `A-B` pair) :

```
             data
A B  C           
1 1  10  2.057864
     5   1.234252
     7   0.235246
  2  7   1.309126
     6   0.450208
     8   0.397360
2 2  2   1.609126
     1   0.250208
     4   0.597360
...
```

Comment: post a original creation of the frame (with code), much easier to copy-paste that way

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. I added a function to create a random dataframe similar to the one I am working with.

Comment: your expected output does not have C sorted?

Comment: @Jeff `C` is sorted according to the data, i.e. it's the index I use within `A-B`.

Comment: oh, ok, then adding a sort after is pretty easy (your question though DOES say to sort by C) :)

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. I will make that clear in the OP. The question still lacks a satisfactory answer, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I 100% understand what you want, but I think this will do it. When you reset it stays in the same order. The key is the `sortlevel()`, it sorts lexiographically the levels (and the remaining levels on ties). In 0.14 (coming soon) their is an option `sort_remaining` which you can play with I think.

```
In [48]: np.random.seed(1234)

In [49]:  df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [np.random.random_integers(10) for x in xrange(500)], 
   ....:                      'B' : [np.random.random_integers(10) for x in xrange(500)], 
   ....:                      'C' : [np.random.random_integers(10) for x in xrange(500)],
   ....:                      'data' : randn(500) })
```

First set the index, then sort it and reset.

Then groupby A,B and pull out the first 20 biggest elements.

```
df.set_index(['A','B','C']).sortlevel().reset_index().groupby(
             ['A','B']).apply(lambda x: x.sort(columns='data',ascending=False).head(20)).set_index(['A','B','C'])
Out[8]: 
             data
A B  C           
1 1  1   0.959688
     2   0.918230
     2   0.731919
     10  0.212463
     1   0.103644
     1  -0.035266
  2  8   1.459579
     8   1.277935
     5  -0.075886
     2  -0.684101
     3  -0.928110
  3  5   0.675987
     4   0.065301
     5  -0.800067
     7  -1.349503
  4  4   1.167308
     8   1.148327
     9   0.417590
     6  -1.274146
     10 -2.656304
  5  2  -0.962994
     1  -0.982679
  6  2   1.410920
     6   1.352527
     10  0.510330
     4   0.033275
     1  -0.679686
     10 -0.896797
     1  -2.858669
  7  8  -0.219342
     8  -0.591054
     2  -0.773227
     1  -0.781850
     3  -1.259089
     10 -1.387992
     10 -1.891734
  8  7   1.578855
     2  -0.498898
  9  3   0.644277
     8   0.572177
     2   0.058431
     9  -0.146912
     4  -0.334690
  10 9   0.795346
     8  -0.137661
     10 -1.335385
2 1  9   1.309405
     3   0.328546
     5   0.198422
     1  -0.561974
     3  -0.578069
  2  5   0.645426
     1  -0.138808
     5  -0.400199
     5  -0.513738
     10 -0.667343
     9  -1.983470
  3  3   1.210882
     6   0.894201
     3   0.743652
              ...

[500 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very close. I was hoping to get the output as a  multi-index dataframe with the ordering properties that I mentioned in the OP. If I re-set indices as a post-processing step of your code, wouldn't that destroy the ordering?

Comment: I updated the OP to show the first few entries of what I want.

Comment: ok, revised the answer; you can do almost anything inside the apply FYI

Comment: Thanks. Why use `sortlevel()` and not `sort_index()` in this particular case? (i.e. in your answer)

Comment: FYI. I just started a ticket on this [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7121#issuecomment-43011577)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df.sort('data', ascending=False).set_index('C').groupby(['A', 'B']).data.head(3)
```

Its not the most readable syntax, but will get the job done

```
A  B  C
1  1  9     1.380526
      1     0.903524
      7    -0.112363
   2  2     0.284057
      5     0.131392
      1     0.111512
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't output what I asked in the OP (see the example I had in the `Update`). The output that you included in your answer doesn't match what I get with your code. The code you have returns a series with only one index, `C`. There is also an extra `)` parenthesis at the end of your code.

Comment: I removed the extra spurious parenthesis. I'm using 0.12.0 on Python 2.7, if that matters

Comment: Hmm I am on `0.13.1` (master from a few days ago) on Python 2.7. I wonder if something changed ...

Comment: You could try a similar approach but different syntax - df.sort('data', ascending=False).groupby(['A', 'B']).head(3).reset_index(drop=True).set_index(['A', 'B', 'C']).data